# Back In Time Configuration Missing?

Tags: kubuntu, backup, 17.04, backintime

I've been backing up my system using Back in Time, and I recently had to reinstall my OS due to errors occurring on the OS. I can't seem to find the Back In Time Config file on my external HDD. The folder structure isn't clearly labeled, so trying to find the config file seems a bit difficult. Is there a certain place in the folder structure I have to look? How can I find the config file?
[image: Backup Folder]

Edit 0: It should be noted that I do have an Encfs6.xml file, this may be the config file, but it doesn't appear as an option when trying to restore the configuration upon booting the Back in Time program and navigating to the directory.
[image: Encfs6.xml]

Answer (score 1):

From [Ubuntu Manpages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man1/backintime-config.1.html) your **BackInTime** configuration files are kept in:

```
~/.config/backintime/config
/etc/backintime/config
```

You might want to read the whole link though for a deeper understanding of BackInTime.

Comment: So, the config file isn't saved to the external drive? Do I need the config file to restore from the external drive? The original OS was reinstalled.

Comment: @SarahSzabo You need to search the external drive snapshot backup looking for those configuration directory/file names. Is your question really about "how do I search?" in BackInTime rather than "what are the configuration names?"

Comment: Well, my general question was about that I couldn't find the configuration file and generally about how to resolve the problem. What exactly are the configuration directories though? The backup was encrypted, everything seems like a bunch of random text.

Comment: @SarahSzabo the backups are likely compressed which can look like encryption. During recovery your steps are to resinstall OS, reinstall apps (like BackInTime) and then use the BackInTime app to restore backups. BackInTime should be able to decompress the backup information and let you select files to restore. I think you shouldn't need to worry about the older configuration files to restore the data which you really care about. Keep in mind I don't use Kubuntu or BackInTime--These are just general industry standards.

Comment: That's the problem though. I've done all of that, but when I go to back in time, it asks for a config file which I believe was on the formatted disk. There appears to be no way of restoring the system without it, which doesn't make a lot of sense considering that this is a backup program that expects something funny happened to the disk causing a loss of data... either that, or I can't figure out how to restore without the config file.

Answer (score 1):

From Germar (Dev on Back in Time):

Your backup is encrypted with encfs. You need to mount the encrypted files manually to be able to copy your config.

Open a Terminal and type:

> `mkdir ~/mnt
>   encfs "/media/<YOUR_USER>/SENTINEL/Ubuntu Backup" ~/mnt`

It will ask for your password. Now start BiT. It will ask to restore your config and should find it in ~/mnt automatically. Restore the config, close BiT and unmount encfs with fusermount -u ~/mnt. Finally you can start BiT again and restore all your files.

Some Notes:

--SENTINEL, is the name of my external hard drive, and the folder Ubuntu Backup is the folder where the encrypted/compressed files are stored.

--Sourced from a conversation I had with Germar on the Back in Time Issues Page

Comment: I needed to use sudo for the encfs command in Kubuntu 18.04 and the latest Ubuntu.